# How to know the social networking websites security level

Tags: internet, security, youtube, facebook, user-data

Is there some app to monitor the social networking websites' (Facebook, YouTube, etc.) security level? I'm talking about how to know if there are some people trying to take our place and/or steal our identity.

Is there something like this? Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox click menu icon <kbd>≡</kbd> in the top right corner -> *Preferences* -> *Privacy & Security* -> *Security* settings. Check the options to *Block dangerous and deceptive content*, *Block dangerous downloads*, and *Warn you about unwanted and uncommon software*.

[image]

In Firefox menu icon <kbd>≡</kbd> in the top right corner -> *Preferences* -> *Privacy & Security* -> *Browser Privacy* there is a choice of three options for Enhanced Tracking Protection: Standard, Strict and Custom. Enhanced Tracking Protection gives the user additional protection against misuse of his/her user data by unwanted third parties.

---

With [Firefox Monitor](https://monitor.firefox.com/), you can keep an eye out for data breaches on multiple email accounts all in one place.

[image]